# Как можно начать использовать Яндекс Карты для продукта как Traccar?

Tags: яндекс-карты

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно начать использовать Яндекс Карты для продукта как Traccar?

Использую как [пользовательский слой](https://www.traccar.org/map-layers/).
Traccar используется для личных целей (хранение).

Answer (score 0):

[Тайлы Яндекса](https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/tiles/?from=mapsapi) для внешних сервисов, не построенных на их JS API, доступны, как отдельный платный API. Договариваетесь с сервисом о подходящем тарифе, оплачиваете и используете.

Если карта Яндекса нужна бесплатно, следует использовать их API и соблюдать [условия бесплатного тарифа](https://yandex.ru/dev/jsapi-v2-1/doc/ru/v2-1/terms/index). А значит карта должна быть публичной и мониторинг объектов вести нельзя.